# package org.opencv.calib3d does not exist

Tags: opencv, cmake, opencv3.0

After multiple attempts I keep getting this error. Apparently when I run cmake

```
opencv_calib3d dependency can't be resolved
```

I'm not sure how to resolve it, no other libraries seem to be missing; I have calib3d in the modules directory of opencv-3.1.0, and I've installed all basic opencv libraries. In general, everything else seems to be working just fine. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

try suffixing the version :

```
opencv_calib3d310 //for opencv 3.1
```